# Чат на сайте

Tags: php

Как создать чат? Надо код. Пожалуйста помогите, надо поле: имя, текст сообщения.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Теперь я себя вспоминаю =) 
Значит делаем такую штуку:

1. Создаем таблицу `Messages`
2. В ней создаем 3 столбика
3. Первый столбик - `id`, второй - `username` и третий - `time`
4. Создаем два файла `chat.php` и `iframe.php`
5. В файл `chat.php` ставим такое:

Код:

```
<script>

    jQuery(function($) {
        $("#form").onsubmit(function (event) {
            var message = $("input[name='message']", form).value()
            if (message) { event.preventDefault(); return false; }
            return true;
        });
        $("#form input[name='message']").bind(
            'change keydown keypress',
            function(event) {
                var text = $(this).value().replace(/^\s+/, "").replace(/\s+$/, "");
                $("#form input[type='submit']").prop("disabled", text == "");
            }
        );
    });
  </script>
  <html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  <iframe name='chatWindow' id='chatWindow' src ="iframe.php" width="850" height="400"></iframe>
  <form action="iframe.php" method="post" id="form" target='chatWindow' > 
  </body>
</html>
```

- А в iframe.php ставим такое :

Код:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
      $message = $_POST['message'];

  }

  $db = mysql_connect("", "", "");
  mysql_select_db("", $db);
  if (trim($message) != "") {
      $time = time();
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO messages (message,username,time) VALUES ('$message','{$_SESSION['username']}','$time')");
  }

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM messages");

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
      echo "<br>";
      echo "[".date(' H:i ',$row['time'])."]".$row['username']."  : ".$row['message'];

  }

?>
```

Все радуйся. Если что, стучись в Скайп komar12124.